# how to wrap element when width is less than max width?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I want to show `two column` layout or `two box in a row` when with is more than `600px` .but when width is less than 600 it should come `1 below another` or other words to wrap the `box`

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cartwright-pw2mq?file=/src/styles.css:182-396

```
<div class="abc">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>


.abc {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px dotted pink;
}
.card {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

my issue is it is not wrapping the box when width is less than `600`.

[image]

Comment: the second box is wrapping to next line when the width is getting shrinked! am I missing anything here?

Comment: didn't get ..I am expecting that behavior..but not working

Comment: I just added a picture in your question, the second box is wrapping it to next line.

Comment: see in `full screen mode`

Comment: there are a right side icon click on that `it will go in full scrren mode`

Comment: Got it! I have added the answer and image with full screen.

Comment: did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using CSS Media Query. something like this.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.abc {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`DIV` is by default `block` so to retain the size of the card `display:inline-block;`.

```
.abc {
 display: flex;
 max-width: 600px;
 justify-content: space-around;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 border: 2px dotted pink;
}
 .card {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid;
 margin: 5px;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .abc {
  display: inline-block;
   }
  }
```

Full screen wrapping around:

[image]